# Comparing 1st order and 2nd order Butterworth bandpass filter on dummy sensor data graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, filter

I am generating dummy sensor data and comparing 1st and 2nd order bandpass filter impact on the signals using following code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal 

#Set configutations
ORDER_COUNT = 3
MAX_BUFFER_SZ = 10000
FRAME_SZ = 500

F_S = 100  # Sampling frequency
F_LOW = 10  # Lower cutoff frequency
F_HIGH = 300  # Higher cutoff frequency

def butter_band(cutoff, fs, order=5, btype='band'):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = cutoff[0] / nyq
    high = cutoff[1] / nyq
    b, a = signal.butter(order, [low, high], btype=btype, analog=False, fs=fs)
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(x, cutoff, fs, order = 5):
    b, a = butter_band(cutoff, fs, order = order, btype = 'band')
    return signal.filtfilt(b, a, x, padlen = len(x)-1)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(ORDER_COUNT, 1, figsize=(8, 4*ORDER_COUNT))

lines = []
all_lines = []
data_buffer = []

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    line, = ax.plot([], [])
    lines.append(line)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
    ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
 
def update(frame):
    new_data = np.random.randn(1)
    data_buffer.append(new_data)
    if len(data_buffer) > MAX_BUFFER_SZ:
        data_buffer.pop(0)
    x_data = np.arange(len(data_buffer))
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
        if (i):
            ax.set_ylabel('Filter with order: ' + str(i))
            filtered_data = butter_bandpass_filter(np.array(data_buffer).flatten(), [F_LOW, F_HIGH], F_S, order=i)
        else:
            ax.set_ylabel('Original Signal')
            filtered_data = data_buffer
        lines[i].set_data(x_data, np.array(filtered_data))
        ax.set_xlim(max(0, len(data_buffer) - FRAME_SZ), len(data_buffer))
        all_lines.append(lines[i])
    return all_lines

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=FRAME_SZ, blit=True, interval=0.5)
plt.show()
```

However, I found that the filtered signal graph is changing (flickering in the mid of frames) over time. Is that an expected behavior or it a problem? I the graph should change only for the new appended data part.